# Parse login with phone number (no password)

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, twilio

Using Parse.com, I want my users to login only with their phone number, just like WhatsApp.

Enter your phone number, get a verification code by SMS, enter the code - you are logged in and stay logged-in!

I can see how I can use Twilio to send a verification code.

My problem is how to tie it in with the Parse authentication framework.

- When to use signUp vs login?
- What is the password?
- What to do the second time the app is launched?
- What to do when the application is re-installed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the predefined Signup and login classes provided by parse as they do not allow you to create a user without a password,
Nor should you use the Anonymous Users as the data will be lost once the user sign out/uninstall.

For Signup, Use another object to store the numbers , Implement a onSave hook in cloud code to ensure that all the username"phone nos" are unique during Signing in.

For each device, perform an OPT(one time password) to the phone of the user by using the installation class's id

Perform a query and load the data connected to the number during Login

To keep the user logged in , use the local data store , pin a Boolean variable that indicates the status of a user, either logged in or out.

In the parse DB , You can use the phone num as the link to the other data of the user.
In this way, no password , only OTP

Comment: I would just add  that if you are planning on creating your own 'User'  class rather than using the one given by Parse, you may wish to pay particular attention to the security of that class, to ensure the users data isn't vulnerable.

Comment: Yep , Definitely add extra security , But Using only the phone number is insecure as someone can "borrow your phone" and access your details on another device.
    you can add a field in the installation class to check whether the device is verified or not via the OTP.

Comment: I agree with you. I was talking more along the lines of using ACL's for the class, to ensure that someone can't just make a query to access all the phone numbers for everyone using the application, as that would kind of be a breach of privacy!

Comment: Was it successfull?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store something on the user settings/profile to pin that user, I do not recommend using a boolean but rather something that ties that device with the user so that if someone decides to copy that file and paste it into a rooted phone you will be able to determine if the app install corresponds to that user.

I would recommend using the a unique token to create a password for a user in Parse.com - you can use the token that RingCaptcha generates for this, ensuring it will never collide with other users and that every phone number will only be able to verify one time for each device. RC is a new service that helps you onboard verified users into your apps in seconds via SMS. Integration is a breeze with all the available plugins for web, APIs, and SDKs of all flavours.

[Disclaimer: I'm part of the team behind RingCaptcha]